# Does Azure Notification Hub *require* Azure-specific client-side code?

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-notificationhub

Our use case is to have an, Azure hosted, web back-end send notification messages to our existing mobile Android and iOS applications. I note from the Azure Notification Hub (ANH) documentation show that we can send messages down to both Android (Google Cloud Messaging and Firebase Cloud Messaging) and iOS.

I also note that all the tutorial samples include you placing ANH-specific code into the mobile clients.

Will ANH work assuming we have only platform-specific calls (e.g. Firebase for Android and Apple Push Notification Service for iOS) in our mobile apps - and no ANH-specific code in the apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you and depends on your scenario/architecture. ANH as a platform doesn't *require* specific client-side code.

Here's a typical high-level architecture (which does have client-side ANH-specific code):
[image]

If you can design your system in such a way that the back-end can register PNS handles by itself (i.e. step 2 on the picture will be different), then you don't need ANH-specific code on the client. In other words, if you can somehow register tokens from the back-end instead of doing it from the client, there's no reason why NH would restrict you from doing that.

If I understood your case correctly, you already have a number of app users that you want to push to using ANH. You'll need to find a way to register tokens of those devices with NH. You can literally do it by writing a simple console app and running it from your laptop as long as you have those tokens available. And then use the Azure back-end in a usual way to do actual pushes, since the push part doesn't care how the devices got registered.

Comment: What do you mean by "tokens"?  We plan on having a custom WebAPI "registration" API that takes a GUID (per device) and user-identifier...but that's our stuff.  Do you mean 'token' as in Firebase instance token or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I need to be more consistent with terminology. "Tokens", "handles", "keys" (and sometimes other terms) are often used interchangeably to denote native PNS device identifiers (tokens for Apple, keys for Android etc). Those then get 'registered' with ANH.

Comment: I believe the picture in the [Registration Management discussion](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management/#registration-management-from-a-backend) may be more relevant to my use case.  Assuming yes, any idea what the "PNS-handle" would be for Firebase?  Would the `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` value work?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Firebase specifically, but it looks like you're correct about the `getToken()` method. This is the method that is used [in the official Notification Hubs Android tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started/#create-a-project-that-supports-firebase-cloud-messaging) to do registrations.